# Load php file in web browser control

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with my system. I want to load a .php file into a web browser control, but whenever I tried to load my local php file it only displays the php codes. This is what I did:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("E:\jnuSite\index.php")
```

How can I fix this? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your web browser control cant process the PHP code, you need a server to do that then display the produced client code in your browser control. I think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for any PHP script to work on a web browser, it must be enabled on your server, which could be an actual server or your computer. If it isn't configured properly, or at all, then you will always see the script you wrote instead of it performing its task.

There are many tutorials online about how to setup a local server using your computer provided you have the permissions set to do so.

Hope this helped, good luck!

(Sorry for not using comments for this, as its not really an answer but at this point I don't have enough rep to post a comment...)

Comment: thanks for this very informative answer. I already got it, I just have to navigate to "localhost" instead of the php file itself. thanks mate!